# Storing non-square images in a volume

Tags: cuda

I have been trying to store non-square images into a volume. My code works when I want to store, 512 times, a square image of size `w512 x h512`, but it does not work for a non-square image of size `w512 x h1024`. I get an error with a description of `unspecified launch failure` at this line: `gpuErrchk( cudaDeviceSynchronize() );` I am not sure why that is happening? I have tried to set my code up so that it accesses data in a coalesced fashion. Is there an alternate solution to my problem?

This is my kernel:

```
__global__ void 
copySlice2Volume2(float *buffer, float *slice, int height, int width, int frameIdx) 
{

    int tid = (blockIdx.x * width) + threadIdx.x;
    buffer[tid + (frameIdx*width*height)] = slice[tid]; 

    __syncthreads();

}
```

The following is the function that calls the above kernel:

```
void testStorage() {

    int nFrames = 512;

    int width = 0;
    int height = 0;

    // 8-bit unsigned char images
    Mat frame, floatFrame;

    frame = imread("C:/Matlab code/im.png", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE); 

    // convert uchar images to float images
    frame.convertTo(floatFrame, CV_32F, 1.0/255.0f);

    width = frame.step;
    height = frame.rows;

    cout << "width: " << width << " height: " << height << endl;
    float *gpuBuffer;
    float *testImage;

    gpuErrchk( cudaMalloc( (void**) &gpuBuffer, sizeof(float) * width * height * nFrames));         // storage init for buffer
    gpuErrchk( cudaMemset(gpuBuffer, 0, sizeof(float) * width * height * nFrames)); // set mem to 0 

    gpuErrchk( cudaMalloc( (void**) &testImage, sizeof(float) * width * height ));          // storage init for image
    gpuErrchk( cudaMemset(testImage, 0, sizeof(float) * width * height ));  // set mem to 0

    gpuErrchk( cudaMemcpy( testImage, floatFrame.ptr<float>(), sizeof (float) * width * height, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice) );

    // num of threads
    dim3 Threads(width); 
    // num of blocks
    dim3 Blocks(height); 

    for(int i = 0; i < nFrames; i++)
    {
        copySlice2Volume2<<< Blocks, Threads >>> (gpuBuffer, testImage, width, height, i);  

    }

    gpuErrchk( cudaDeviceSynchronize() );    // error here

    printf("Cuda status2: %s\n", cudaGetErrorString( cudaGetLastError() ) );

    gpuErrchk( cudaFree(gpuBuffer) );
    gpuErrchk( cudaFree(testImage) );

    }
```

Comment: Why are width and height reversed in the arguments supplied to the kernel call?

Comment: @talonmies D'oh! I totally missed that! Code works now, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The width and height arguments were switched in the kernel call, and that was the reason for the error. Everything works once that was corrected. This is the corrected kernel:

```
__global__ void 
copySlice2Volume2(float *buffer, float *slice, int width, int height, int frameIdx) 
{

    int tid = (blockIdx.x * width) + threadIdx.x;
    buffer[tid + (frameIdx*width*height)] = slice[tid]; 

    __syncthreads();

}
```